# Get one JSON value with another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON string:

```
{
"XXX": {
  "x": "1",
  "y": "2"
},
"XXX": {
  "x": "3",
  "y": "3"
  }
}
```

What I wanna do is like find the x-value (Where it equals to 1 or something.) and then find the y-value next to.
How can I do this?

I wanna do this with JavaScript

Comment: *"I wanna do this with JQuery or JavaScript"* Well, go ahead, then. Ask a question here when you get stuck. (BTW, jQuery *is* Javascript.)

Comment: I don't know what created this JSON, but an object with the same property twice in it won't give you the result you might expect. I'm not even sure wether all JSON parser will return you the same result or not just throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse it and Iterate over it

```js
var data = JSON.parse('{"XXX":{"x":"1","y":"2"},"XXX":{"x":"3","y":"3"}}');

var y = 0;
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert('With Jquery X = '+item.x);
    alert('With Jquery Y = '+item.y);
    //if you want to get the value of y based on x or vice versa then check
    if(item.x == 3) {
       y = item.y;
    }   
 });
    // Then you can use the value of y here.
    alert('This is the matching Y = '+ y);
    
    
    
    
    // With Plain Js
    for(key in data) {
  alert( 'With Plain JS X = '+data[key].x );
    alert( 'With Plain JS Y = '+data[key].y );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But XXX is unknown so i wanna do like find where X = 2 and get Y from there.

Comment: @Ras.M You don't need to know the xxx key. Read the code its not refering to xxx, its giving you the value of xxx on every iteration and as you know its an object so you can just get the value of x and y from it

Comment: Also, the above code will give you only 3 for x and y. As the key for both the objects is same viz xxx so the last one takes the value of the xxx in the parsed object

Comment: When i run the code i only get the last X and Y but not the first pair.

Answer (score 0):

Using Json parse.

A simple exemple:

```js
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[1].lastName;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML =
obj.employees[2].firstName + " " + obj.employees[2].lastName;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[2].lastName;
```

```html
<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Comment: I wanna do like Where firstName = John get lastName